# How to bind React-csv with props which are empty initially?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, export-to-csv

```
const props{
    csvData: events[]
}
<CSVLink data={csvData}>Download me</CSVLink>;
```

I am trying to use react-CSV and export table as CSV but the initial value of the event is empty and CSVLink throwing error of undefined value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to conditionally render the CSVLink component once there is csvData available.

```
const props{
    csvData: events[]
}
if (csvData?.length > 0) {
    return <CSVLink data={csvData}>Download me</CSVLink>;
}
return (<p>Waiting for data...</p>)
```

Comment: I got a workaround which was there in react-CSV to use async function